# How can I make a non-permanent session in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning flask and am trying to associate some randomly generated data with each session.
I use the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37754039/3752268) to set session.permanent to False, but closing the browser, then reopening it at going back to the page still displays the same code.

MWE:

```
from flask import Flask, session
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "supersecretkey"

@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = False

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'id' not in session:
        random_id = "".join(np.random.choice(list("abcdefg123"), 16))
        session["id"] = random_id
    return session['id']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Update: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37234681/3752268) someone recommended to use socketio to notice disconnects. This also makes no difference, i.e. closing the browser, reopening it, and going to 127.0.0.1:5000 gives the same number as before closing. An updated MWE using this is below:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "supersecretkey"

@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = False

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'id' not in session:
        random_id = "".join(np.random.choice(list("abcdefg123"), 16))
        session["id"] = random_id
    return session['id']

socketio = SocketIO(app)
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect_user():
    session.pop('id', None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Which route do you call after reopening?

Comment: does this help as a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227780/flask-session-persisting-after-close-browser

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I just navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000 again.

Comment: @gittert No, I tried doing something similar to no avail. I'm updating the MWE to reflect this.

Comment: @ahura again? after reopening you just set a new `id`

Comment: @ahura **Note: after edited the question**. The problem related with `socketio` or sessions in `Flask`?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Instantiate a new web application called `app`, 
# with `__name__` representing the current file
app = Flask(__name__) 

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
```